# Kubernetes Health Check: timeoutSeconds exceeds periodSeconds

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check, readinessprobe, livenessprobe

In Kubernetes [`Kubernetes Health Check Probes`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/), what happens if `timeoutSeconds` exceeds `periodSeconds`? For example:

```
initialDelaySeconds: 10
periodSeconds: 5
timeoutSeconds: 10
successThreshold: 1
failureThreshold: 3
```

When will the Pod "fail"?

- `initialDelaySeconds` + (`periodSeconds` * `failureThreshold`); or
- `initialDelaySeconds` + ( `MAX`(`periodSeconds`,`timeoutSeconds`) * `failureThreshold`);

Same question applies for when the Pod succeeds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a diagram in this [blog post](https://www.openshift.com/blog/liveness-and-readiness-probes) which illustrate your question clearly:

[image: Probe Timeline]

The pod will be restarted at lowest,

> time = initialDelay + (failureThreshold - 1) * period + timeout

- `timeoutSeconds` > `periodSeconds` ?

The probe call will be fired at a given interval independent of the previous probe response. The `failureThreshold` will be checked, once the probe call is passed or failed/timeout. But it is recommended to use `periodSeconds` greater than the `timeoutSeconds`.