# Kubernetes Health Probe periodSeconds Clarification

Tags: kubernetes

I have a question around health probes in Kubernetes.

Take the below example:

```yaml
          startupProbe:
            exec:
              command: ["python", "health.py"]
            initialDelaySeconds: 0
            timeoutSeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 10
            failureThreshold: 2
```

Regarding **periodSeconds**....

Lets say my script **health.py**  takes longer than 10 seconds to run for whatever reason, does Kubernetes try and run my health check again regardless of whether the first run is finished or does it wait until the first run is finished, then wait 10 seconds to run another? This is not clear in the documentation...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes Health Check: timeoutSeconds exceeds periodSeconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66687912/kubernetes-health-check-timeoutseconds-exceeds-periodseconds)

Answer (score 0):

When your script **health.py** takes longer than 10 seconds to run, Kubernetes will still try to run the readiness probe at the specified interval. If the first run takes longer than 10 seconds, Kubernetes will wait for the first run to finish before running the next probe. The next probe will be executed after the specified interval, which is 10 seconds in your case.

This behavior ensures that the pod is only marked as ready when it meets the specific criteria defined by your application. If the script **health.py** takes longer than 10 seconds to run, the pod will be marked as unready until the script completes successfully.

See this [document](https://komodor.com/blog/kubernetes-health-checks-everything-you-need-to-know/) to know more about Kubernetes health checks